# Normal position of Electrical axis only in the III lead?

Tags: physiology, electrocardiography

I found this sentence in my notes which is not exact enough:

> Electrical axes
>
> - Excitatory processes have definite direction and magnitude and could therefore be represented as vectors. At any moment there are two
>     points in the heart with the biggest potential difference, which is
>     called electrical axis, characterized by the angel α.
> - Under normal conditions -> 30°< angel α < 90°
> - Electrical axis gives information about the position of the heart, where the normal position ([arrow to south-east]) represents the
>     biggest amplitude in the III lead

**What is the exact electrical axis and of what they are talking about?**

Comment: @kmm This is not anymore discussion-type answer. I specified the question. Please, see also my answer to my question which clarifies something.

Comment: If your answer to the question clarifies it, then why not just edit the question?

Comment: The other question I have: Why do you permanently post questions and their answer within minutes? This is kind of absurd.

Comment: @Chris Because I like the Q&A style, and try to first improve the notes so well as I can and ask your opinion because I cannot be sure that I am right in my thoughts.

Comment: Ah, ok. Most of this is not my field of experience, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the definition of the electrical axis.
The text does not specify which type of electrical axis and of what.
For instance, Guyton discusses Mean Electrical Axis of the Ventricular QRS only.
However, Guyton says that the mean electrical axis of the normal ventricle is 59 degrees. 
In many pathological conditions of the heart, this direction changes markedly, sometimes even to opposite poles of the heart.

So the original author must have considered the Mean Electrical Axis of Ventricular QRS.

I would change the paragraph to

> Mean Electrical axes of the Ventricular QRS
>
> - Excitatory processes have definite direction and magnitude and could
>     therefore be represented as vectors. At any moment there are two
>     points in the heart with the biggest potential difference, which is
>     called electrical axis, characterized by the angel α.
> - Under normal
>     conditions -> 30°< angel α < 90°
> - The Mean Electrical axis of normal ventricles is 59 degrees, which gives information
>     about the position of the heart, and it represents the biggest amplitude in the lead III.